# Insert dates in MySql database table?

Tags: php, mysql, date, ip

I'm building a login application, and I want to store the date the user registered and the last login date as well as the last login ip.

When creating the table what type should I give each of these three columns?

How would I proceed when I insert a new username and other data?

Should I use PHP to get the register date or should I use mysql's current date?

For the last login date and ip, what way do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When creating the table what type should I give each of these three
>   columns?

make `create_date` and `last_login_date` both `DATETIME`'s and `last_login_ip` a `VARCHAR`

> Should I use PHP to get the register date or should I use mysql's
>   current date?

This doesn't matter unless you are required to not use MySQL specific functions.

> For the last login date and ip, what way do I do it?

When a user logs in, run an update statement that fills `last_login_date` with the current timestamp and `last_login_ip` with the contents of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Comment: I see, this is very useful. So I will make the `register_date` and `last_login_date` as Date ( the type ), but my question for these two is: Should I set their `Attributes` in the MySql table as `on update CURRENT TIMESTAMP` or should I leave that alone, and as for their values, what should I add, nothing ? And for the last_login_ip, it's value in the table should I leave it empty ? For the moment I won't have any user in the table, so it shouldn't be any value for any of it I guess.

Comment: Make them `DATETIME` (not `DATE`, which is another type in mysql). Update the date manually (no `TIMESTAMP`), e.g., `UPDATE users SET last_login_date = NOW() WHERE id = 1`. Regarding, `last_login_ip`, it's completely up to you if you wish to fill it with data or not.

Comment: Also what length should I set for `register_date` and `last_login_date` ?

Comment: Those are `DATETIME` columns. They don't require a length.

Answer (score 1):

```
CreatedDate    : datetime
LastLoginDate  : datetime
LastLoginIp    : varchar(20)
```

Check this link to see how to get ip of the user.
http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_ip.php

When the user tries to login , you check the username and password against a database and if the user is valid get the user IP and update your table to have this ip address as the value for "LastLoginIp" column.

Answer (score 1):

For `createdDate` and `lastLoginDate` use `datetime` fields, for the IP Address an `int` field and insert the data via PHP's `ip2long()` function, see [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php).

To retrieve the data, you can do it on MySQL level:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) FROM 'log' WHERE
```

To get the real IP address, you want to check for proxies as well:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
//Is it a proxy address
}elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```